# What is known about the homomorphisms from local to global Weil groups?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, langlands-conjectures

I have been reading Tate's article *Number Theoretic Background* in the Corvallis proceedings about the Weil and Weil-Deligne groups. I understand that the global Weil group $W_K$ of a number field $K$ has only an abstract construction, while the local Weil groups $W_{K_v}$ have a relatively concrete realization as a dense subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v)$.

Suppose we have chosen a global Weil group $W_K$, and for each place $v$ of $K$, an embedding $\overline{K} \subset \overline{K_v}$ of algebraic closures.  Then this defines a continuous homomorphism $\theta_v: W_{K_v} \rightarrow W_K$.

What is known about these homomorphisms?  Some "basic" things I have been wondering:

- Are they injective?
- Do the images of the $W_{K_v}$, as $v$ runs through the places of $K$, generate $W_K$?  Or if that is not true, is a continuous finite dimensional representation of $W_K$ at least determined by its "restriction" to the $W_{K_v}$?
- What is the effect of composing $\theta_v$ by an inner automorphism of $W_K$?